# network interface does not become active although onboot enabled

Tags: networking, fedora, configuration

Due to some other conflicts, I disabled/stopped NetworkManager in Fedora 15,

Now, for network configuration I used system-config-network-gui to config & enable Ethernet interface,

Problem is, when system starts, the Ethernet does not become enabled. Although in configuration through system-config-network, I specifically checked "Activate device when computer starts" "Allow all users to enable and disable the device",

and cleared "Controlled by NetworkManager"

I double checked the config file "/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0" to see if the configurations are saved correctly and onboot is enabled. And they look OK.

so, Why still it does not become enabled automatically on boot?

```
# Atheros Communications AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=yes
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
NAME="System eth0"
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
DNS2=4.2.2.4
DNS1=8.8.8.8
IPADDR0=192.168.0.200
PREFIX0=24
GATEWAY0=192.168.0.1
DNS3=192.9.9.3
HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
IPADDR=192.168.0.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
NM_CONTROLLED=no
PREFIX=24
```

Comment: Please show `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0` contents

Comment: `# Atheros Communications AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=yes
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
NAME="System eth0"
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
DNS2=4.2.2.4
DNS1=8.8.8.8
IPADDR0=192.168.0.200
PREFIX0=24
GATEWAY0=192.168.0.1
DNS3=192.9.9.3
HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
IPADDR=192.168.0.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
NM_CONTROLLED=no
PREFIX=24`

Comment: using the `system-config-network-cmd` I got furthur with the troubleshooting. It seems that somehow the DNS is mis-configured in the file, although I have always used the system-network-config commands to add DNS server. Here is extract of `system-config-network-cmd`
`Component: system-config-network`
`Version: 1.6.2`
File "/usr/sbin/system-config-network-cmd", line 292, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: **24DNS2=4.2.2.4**

`Local variables in innermost frame:`
`confkey: ONBOOT`
`DevEthernet.Prefix=24DNS2=4.2.2.4`
`DevEthernet.PrimaryDNS=8.8.8.8`

Comment: correcting the file, still did not help, and the system boots up without its network interfaces enabled.

Answer (score 3):

`BOOTPROTO=static` in `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0` would solve you problem

But it seems that you got a bug described in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=698738):

> ifup doesn't assign address specified with IPADDR0

My recomenration is to use `vim` or `nano` for edit `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
# Atheros Communications AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit or Fast Ethernet
DEVICE=eth0
UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME="System eth0"
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=192.168.0.200
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=4.2.2.4
DNS3=192.9.9.3
USERCTL=yes
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
```

Comment: Thanks dchirikov, I also changed bootproto=none to `bootproto=static` I'm testing to see the result.
good link to the bugzilla. cheers